# mongodb query nested structure

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How can I query this nested json structure in order to find documents that contain "A"?

```
"categories":[{"id":12,"values":[["A","B","C"]]},{"id":17,"values":[["D","E","F"]]}]
```

So far, I only managed to get to the id value with

```
db.coll.find( {categories: { $elemMatch: { id: 12 }}} )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to nest the [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operators to match the nested levels of your arrays to match the element:

```js
db.coll.find({
    "categories": { 
        "$elemMatch": { 
            "values": { 
                "$elemMatch": {
                    "$elemMatch": { "$in": ["A"] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Although Neil's answer will work, you can do it with only two `$elemMatch` operators, instead of three to make it simpler.

You can use [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to get to the `values` property and then you can use nested `$elemMatch` operators to check the nested array value:

```
db.coll.find({
    "categories.values" : { 
        $elemMatch : { 
            $elemMatch : { $in : ["A", "B"] }
        }
    }
});
```